# TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider Strange Characters

Tags: c#

I am trying to decrypt some text that I encrypted, however, I get strange characters:

ﶇ쒏栎ル찢샋�㨺⸸⓬왛㓘瞅苽景崲胏퐛㽵㈊褗邌≟䒙쉪ਊᮻ

Here is the encrypted text:

1Cu+45SHXGsSHmJiYuZx3uQYPr6N4vXUwIvzYtDcUs05l4tZZT4jJBjlG6uJbzZgjQOwjRwwTvmowC3FGlbU/IsvM6U3il3i

How can I get regular text?

```
       public static string DecryptData(string encryptedtext, string key)
    {
        key = m_Key;
        try
        {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TripleDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            TripleDes.Key = TruncateHash(key, TripleDes.KeySize / 8);
            TripleDes.IV = TruncateHash("", TripleDes.BlockSize / 8);

            // Convert the encrypted text string to a byte array.
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext);

            // Create the stream.
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            // Create the decoder to write to the stream.
            CryptoStream decStream = new CryptoStream(ms, TripleDes.CreateDecryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            // Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
            decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
            decStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Convert the plaintext stream to a string.
            return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return DecryptDataOldKey(encryptedtext, string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Here is my encrypt code:

```
        public static string EncryptData(string plaintext, string key = "")
    {
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TripleDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        TripleDes.Key = TruncateHash(key, TripleDes.KeySize / 8);
        TripleDes.IV = TruncateHash("", TripleDes.BlockSize / 8);

        // Convert the plaintext string to a byte array.
        byte[] plaintextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext);

        // Create the stream.
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        // Create the encoder to write to the stream.
        CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(ms, TripleDes.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        // Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
        encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length);
        encStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Convert the encrypted stream to a printable string.
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: As an aside, you have quite a good number of object whose classes implement the `IDisposable` interface. You should be wrapping the lifetime of those objects in `using` statements to ensure proper deterministic disposal.

Comment: Also, the `DecryptData()` seems a bit odd - you're overwriting the passed in parameter `key` with a class level member `m_key`. Perhaps you are using different keys to encrypt vs. decrypt here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same encoding when encrypting and decrypting data, for instance **UTF8**. Change **System.Text.Encoding.Unicode** to  **System.Text.Encoding.UTF8**.

Comment: Hi, I am using Unicode to encrypt it. Should I use UTF 8 from now on?